# Using login view provided by django instead of custom login view

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django website. I have my own custom user model. and this is my login view:

```
def login(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            user=auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('/category/all')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Email Password didn't match")
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request,"login.html")
```

I wanted to shift to the login_view provided by django to get features such as next after login which does not happen with my custom view. So in my urls can I just use login view or do i have to make some changes in my templates and user model or is it not possible to shift to pre provided login view after having a custom user model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you direct the user to login page.    Anyway, insert the page you want the user to come back, in a `next` variable like :

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">login</a>
```

Then, in your login form(template) add an extra hidden input `next` :

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">
```

and in login view redirect the user to the next page if the `next` variable in not empty:

```
if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    next_page = request.POST['next']
    if next_page != '':
        return redirect(next_page)
    else:
        return redirect('index')                
else:
```